# How to get SP list versioning properties from WSS_Content database?

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, document-library, csom, content-database

I need to set all list versioning properties via `csom`.
[image: all list versioning settings]

All properties I usually set with following code:

```
SP.List l = new SP.List(...);

l.EnableModeration = true;              //1
l.EnableVersioning = true;              //3    
l.EnableMinorVersions = true;           //4


l.MajorVersionLimit = 1;                //6
l.MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit = 1;      //8

l.DraftVersionVisibility                //9
    = SP.DraftVisibilityType.Approver;
l.ForceCheckout = true;                 //10

//saving
```

I suppose that `'5'`, `'7'` can be set like this:
(I mean with `'0'` value)

```
SP.List l = new SP.List(...);

l.MajorVersionLimit = 0;                //5
l.MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit = 0;      //7
```

And `'2'` like this:

```
SP.List l = new SP.List(...);
l.EnableModeration = false;             //1
```

(according to the picture)
And btw where these properties are stored in `WSS_Content` ?
Some of them could be taken from `AllLists`:

```
SELECT *
  tp_MaxMajorVersionCount,
  tp_MaxMajorwithMinorVersionCount,
  tp_ModerationStatus,

  --contain such properties as: FORCECHECKOUT, MINORVERSIONENABLED, MINORAUTHOR, 
  --MINORAPPROVER, ALLOWEVERYONEVIEWITEMS
  tp_Flags
FROM
  [dbo].[AllLists]
```

Comment: You should not be querying the database. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/841057/support-for-changes-to-the-databases-that-are-used-by-office-server-pr

Comment: @TrevorSeward I do it